# Deleting File and Renaming file in java

Tags: java

i am trying to use this code to replace field and after the replace is done i like to delete the file. But when i replace the file only 1 line was saved. How should i ensure that the other lines will be saved?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    AddChips();
}
public static void AddChips() {
      File oldFile = new File ("players.dat");
      File newFile = new File ("tempchips.dat");

      BufferedReader br = null;
      BufferedWriter bw = null;

      ArrayList<String> player = new ArrayList<String>();
      try {
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(oldFile));
         bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile));
         String line;
         Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Please Enter Username");
         String UserN = read.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Please Enter Chips to Add");
         String UserCadd = read.nextLine();

         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] details = line.split("\\|");
                String Username = details[0];
                String Password = details[1];
                String Chips = details[2];
                int totalChips = (Integer.parseInt(UserCadd)+ Integer.parseInt(Chips));
            if (Username.equals(UserN)){
               line = Username + "|" + Password + "|" + totalChips;
               bw.write(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
                    //issue is here
                    br.close();
                    bw.close();
                    oldFile.delete();
                    newFile.renameTo(oldFile);
                    //AdminMenu();
         } 
      } catch (Exception e) {
         return;
      } finally {
         try {
            if(br != null)
               br.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            //
         }
         try {
            if(bw != null)
               bw.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            //
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: Flush the stream before closing - bw.flush();

Comment: as a means of debugging:  check the length of the file before renaming.  And like MGorgon said, flush the stream before closing, too.

Comment: i'll try your suggestion,

Comment: You close the file in every loop. Think closing shoul be after the loop.

Comment: Closing the stream should flush it actually, I think Jens finds where the bug is: These 4 lines would be out of the loop.

Comment: Let me go try there's a new problem suddenly my new file becomes empty